# Eloquent how to pass parameters to relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

The code I'm trying to fix looks like this. I have an Hotel class which is used in a query to get all hotels in an area but it doesn't discard those which are not available. There's a method inside which should be an accessor but it's not written the way I expected it to be:

```
public function isAvailableInRanges($start_date,$end_date){

        $days = max(1,floor((strtotime($end_date) - strtotime($start_date)) / DAY_IN_SECONDS));

        if($this->default_state)
        {
            $notAvailableDates = $this->hotelDateClass::query()->where([
                ['start_date','>=',$start_date],
                ['end_date','<=',$end_date],
                ['active','0']
            ])->count('id');
            if($notAvailableDates) return false;

        }else{
            $availableDates = $this->hotelDateClass::query()->where([
                ['start_date','>=',$start_date],
                ['end_date','<=',$end_date],
                ['active','=',1]
            ])->count('id');
            if($availableDates <= $days) return false;
        }

        // Check Order
        $bookingInRanges = $this->bookingClass::getAcceptedBookingQuery($this->id,$this->type)->where([
            ['end_date','>=',$start_date],
            ['start_date','<=',$end_date],
        ])->count('id');

        if($bookingInRanges){
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I wanted to filter out hotels using this query. So this is the query from the controller:

```
    $list = $model_hotel->with(['location','hasWishList','translations','termsByAttributeInListingPage'])->get();
```

Is it possible to pass the range of days to the function?

By the way the first thing I tried was to use the collection after the query and pass a filter function through the collection and after that paginate manually but although it does filter, but apparently it loses 
the "Eloquent" result set collection properties and it ends up as a regular collection, thus it doesn't work for me that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the best approach for that is to create a query scope ([source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent)) and put all your logic inside of this function.

after that you can call this scope and pass the dates. Example you will create a query scope and paste your code inside of it.

```
public function scopeisAvailableInRanges($query, $start_date, $end_date) {
}
```

then you will invoke this query scope in your controller like this.

```
$list = $model_hotel::isavailableinranges($start_date, $end_date)->with(['location','hasWishList','translations','termsByAttributeInListingPage'])->get();
```

keep in mind that inside of your query scope you will return a collection. A collection of all your available hotels.